# Where to find HTTP methods examples?

Tags: http, httpwebrequest

[HTTP defines eight methods (sometimes referred to as "verbs")](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP)

Can you help me find examples for each one so I can test and understand them better?

Comment: I guess reading RFC 2616 explains all: http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2616.html

Comment: IMHO absolutely valid question, number of upvotes for the question and the accepted answer show that clearly

Answer (score 58, accepted):

First you should take a look into the [HTTP 1.1 specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html), especially the section [method definitions](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9).

- **OPTIONS**    Get information about how the server allows to communicate with.

  Request:

  ```
  OPTIONS * HTTP/1.1
  Host: example.com
  ```

  Response:

  ```
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  Date: …
  Allow: OPTIONS, GET, HEAD, POST, PUT, DELETE, TRACE
  Content-Length: 0
  ```
- **GET**    Retrieve a resource.

  Request:

  ```
  GET /foo/bar HTTP/1.1
  Host: example.com
  ```

  Response:

  ```
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  Date: …
  Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
  Content-Length: 12345
   
  <!DOCTYPE …
  ```
- **HEAD**   Like **GET**, but returns just the HTTP header.

  Request:

  ```
  HEAD /foo/bar HTTP/1.1
  Host: example.com
  ```

  Response:

  ```
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  Date: …
  Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
  Content-Length: 12345
  ```
- **POST**   Create a new resource.

  Request:

  ```
  POST /foo/bar HTTP/1.1
  Host: example.com
  Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
   
  action=addentry&subject=Hello,%20World
  ```

  Response:

  ```
  HTTP/1.1 201 Created
  Date: …
  Content-Length: 0
  Location: http://example.com/foo/bar
  ```
- **PUT**    Send data to the server.
- **DELETE**   Delete an existing resource.
- **TRACE**   Return the request headers sent by the client.

  Request:

  ```
  TRACE /foo/bar HTTP/1.1
  Host: example.com
  ```

  Response:

  ```
  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
  Date: …
  Content-Length: 17
   
  Host: example.com
  ```

I don’t know exactly if these examples are correct. Feel free to correct them.

Comment: and how to write a put method

Comment: Also how to test these methods? write them where to get the response?

Comment: @Amr ElGarhy: I’ve never used PUT myself. So I cannot give you an example for it.

Comment: Testing is covered in John Topley's answer. That is: for the client side. For the server side you'd need to specify what programming language you're about to use.

Comment: how about the CONNECT method? Here is only 7 HTTP methods example

Comment: @Gumbo you mixed up POST and PUT.

Comment: PUT behaves the same way as POST. POST is intended for creating a new resource, PUT is intended for updating an existing resource.

Comment: @Amr ElGarhy: You can play also with http://httpbin.org/

Comment: very good answer:)

Answer (score 13):

You can experiment with the different HTTP methods using the [cURL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CURL) command line tool. For example:

```
curl --head http://www.google.co.uk

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Date: Sun, 19 Apr 2009 15:33:24 GMT
Expires: -1
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
Set-Cookie: PREF=ID=a2a414b9a84c8ffd:TM=1240155204:LM=1240155204:S=16kZnqzeSxIJT3jv; expires=Tue, 19-Apr-2011 15:33:24 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.co.uk
Server: gws
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
```

- The -X option lets you specify an HTTP method other than GET.

Comment: Good hint, +1. Note that not all browsers support all methods. That's why, for example, Ruby on Rails actually only uses GET and POST, and not PUT and DELETE. If curl does not support all methods, then one can even use telnet to manually invoke them: see for example http://tonycode.com/wiki/index.php?title=Making_HTTP_requests_via_telnet

Comment: Agreed, I've done that with Telnet before.